# How to get cities and states with orders list on Woocommerce

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce

how can I add billing_city and billing_country to the list of orders with woocommerce ?
is there any hook please ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: [This](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-column-to-orders-table-wp-dashboard/) article on Business Bloomer might help